# c# windows form- How to start my application automatically by click Button1

Tags: c#, winforms

Working in windows form application, and I need to close my `work.exe` then wait 4 second time and then start it again with click button1.

is that possible?

```
Application.Exit();
delay(400);
      System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\application.exe");
delay(300);
button1.PerformClick();
```

Comment: are you familiar with creating an orrride method.. just copy past the code I posted in the answer below give it a try..also once this is closed then you can't get at the delay code.. so perhaps you may want to explain also what it is you're trying to do so that I can update my answer appropriately

Comment: Instead of telling us what you're doing, tell us [what you're trying to accomplish](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) because what you're doing can never work.

Comment: If you must do this, start the new instance first, then exit the current running instance.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the Exit method the application closes, so the rest of the code is never executed.

What you can do is to hide it instead of closing it.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the override method and do something like this for instance

```
 protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
 {
    base.OnShown(e);
    this.button1(null, null);
 }
```